# Showing continuity of a real valued function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, connectedness

Let $S=[0,1)\cup [2,3]$ and let $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ be strictly increasing such that $f(S)$ is an connected subset of $\mathbb R$. How to show that $f$ is continuous?

$f(S)$ is connected means it is an interval. Also $f$ is one-one. But I couldn't proceed further. Please suggest!